# Break a list and display its contents over multiple pages

Tags: html, css, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

I'm trying to build a web-app using j2ee. I'm attempting to display a list of items in a table, breaking the list into multiple pages if there are more than 25 items returned.

Here is an example :

[image]

How should I proceed please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if it's database driven then a server side language such as php would suit this very well. pagination in php is relatively easy

Comment: @Vector, I do not know how I say. Looking for how to get by with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring-data to do this.
Your jsp code to show records:

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${page.content}">
   <p>${user.name}</p>
</c:forEach>
```

Your jsp code to show pagination controls (like in attached image):

```
<c:if test="${page.totalPages > 1}">
    <c:set var="THRESHOLD" value="3" />
    <div class="pagination">
        <ul>
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${page.number != 0}">
                    <li><a href="${home}/${targetUrl}?page=${page.number-1}${queryParams}">&larr;</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="${home}/${targetUrl}?page=0${queryParams}">1</a></li>
                    <c:choose>
                        <c:when test="${page.number <  (THRESHOLD + 3)}">
                            <c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="${page.number}">
                                <c:choose>
                                    <c:when test="${i == page.number}"> 
                                        <li class="current"><span>${i+1}</span></li>
                                    </c:when>
                                    <c:otherwise>
                                        <li><a href="${home}/${targetUrl}?page=${i}${queryParams}">${i+1}</a></li>
                                    </c:otherwise>
                                </c:choose>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </c:when>
                        <c:otherwise>
                            <li><span>...</span></li>
                            <c:forEach var="i" begin="${page.number - THRESHOLD}" end="${page.number}">
                                <c:choose>
                                    <c:when test="${i == page.number}"> 
                                        <li class="current"><span>${i+1}</span></li>
                                    </c:when>
                                    <c:otherwise>
                                        <li><a href="${home}/${targetUrl}?page=${i}${queryParams}">${i+1}</a></li>
                                    </c:otherwise>
                                </c:choose>
                            </c:forEach>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <li class="current"><span>1</span></li>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
            <c:if test="${page.number != page.totalPages-1}">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${(page.totalPages - page.number) <  (THRESHOLD + 3)}">
                        <c:forEach var="i" begin="${page.number+1}" end="${page.totalPages-1}">
                            <li><a href="${home}/${targetUrl}?page=${i}${queryParams}">${i+1}</a></li>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <c:forEach var="i" begin="${page.number+1}" end="${page.number + THRESHOLD}">
                            <li><a href="${home}/${targetUrl}?page=${i}${queryParams}">${i+1}</a></li>
                        </c:forEach>
                        <li><span>...</span></li>
                        <li><a href="${home}/${targetUrl}?page=${page.totalPages-1}${queryParams}">${page.totalPages}</a></li>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
                <li><a href="${home}/${targetUrl}?page=${page.number+1}${queryParams}">&rarr;</a></li>
            </c:if>
        </ul>
    </div>
</c:if>
```

simply replace ${targetUrl} and ${queryParams} with your controller url and needed params

Your controller:

```
    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/your-controller-url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String adminUsersList(@RequestParam(required = false) Integer page, Model model) {
        if(page == null) {
            page = 0;
        }
        PageRequest pageReq = new PageRequest(page, "15", new Sort(new Order(Direction.ASC, "id"))); // 15 - is number of items on page
        Page<User> usersPage = userDao.findAll(pageReq);
        model.addAttribute("page", usersPage);
        return "your-view-name";
    }
```

And UserDAO:

```
public interface UserDAO extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

To have better understanding whats going on read this awesome tutorial: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-data-jpa-tutorial/